# XPath text/replace to find text which may contain soft-hyphen

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, soft-hyphen

Searching for a text: `Bescheinigungen` my XPath should also return elements which include a soft-hyphen like: `Beschei\u00ADnigungen`.

I tried this:

```
//*[text()[replace(., "\u00AD", "")="Bescheinigungen"]]
```

Doesn't work. Need some help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, had to use some 'helper' code to make it work:

```
public static WebElement findByText(WebDriver driver, String text) {
  List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[text()]"));
  return elements.stream().filter(element -> {
    String elementText = element.getText();
    if (elementText != null && !elementText.isEmpty()) {
      return text.equals(elementText.replace("\u00AD", ""));
    }
    return false;
  }).findFirst().orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new);
}
```